# Selecting Dates in a Query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to make a query for a set of dates in MS Access.

*In English I would like to choose all entries that are older than 2003 but less than 2006 for Group 1 and Group 2 (4 groups in total) EXCEPT [2005-09-09 in Group 1] and [2005-10-03 and 2005-10-04 in Group 2].*

Here is what I have so far:

```
WHERE 
Group = "1"   AND
Group = "2"   AND
  (Year(Date) = 2004 AND
   Year(Date) = 2005)
```

However I have quickly gotten confused as to how to incorporate the exceptions. Also is it possible to include more than one selection criteria for group or Year for one line? Could anyone possibly help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled using `AND/OR` logic

Try this `Where` clause

```
WHERE 
(
(Group = '1'  AND Date() <> #2005-09-09#)
OR 
(Group = '2'  AND DATE() NOT IN (#2005-10-03# , #2005-10-04#)
) 
AND 
(Year(Date()) between 2004 AND 2005)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work though it is obviously close. For some reason, this: `Date != '2005-09-09'` seems to be a problematic piece of code. I get a syntax error except when I remove that piece. However, when I remove that piece, I get the following error message: `this expression is typed incorrectly or is too complex`. Any ideas?

Comment: @boshek - May its is because of `!=` operator try replacing with `<>`. Updated check now

Comment: @boshek - `!=` is the problem in `MS-ACCESS` for **NOT EQUAL TO** it is `<>`. Here is the official link  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Table-of-operators-e1bc04d5-8b76-429f-a252-e9223117d6bd

Comment: Yes that worked though I still get this error message `This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated.  For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements.  Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables`

Comment: @boshek - Now am not sure about that error.. Am not a ms-access expert.. But this is the idea to get it done.. plus this is a valid syntax in most of the `DBMS`.. Lets wait for some ms-access guru's to jump in

Comment: Dates have to be enclosed in `#` in access not single quotes.